# sql problem adding index column to table with data

Tags: sql

I am a NOVICE SQL ADMIN... I am trying to add a column 'ID' as Identity Primary Key Index to a Table with 212K rows Tickers Table = (date, open, high, low, close, volume, tickers).

When I issue this statement...

ALTER TABLE TICKERS ADD ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL

I Get this message...

The transaction log for database 'TRADE' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

When I do this... select * from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions

I get this.. (which I think is the problem, cause their are 0 Open Transactions, just these Active Transactions..)

155 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

159 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

161 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

163 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

167 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

171 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

175 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

179 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

183 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

185 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

188 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

190 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

194 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

198 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

202 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

206 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

208 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

210 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

212 worktable   2009-11-15 16:48:47.593 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

17261   SELECT  2009-11-15 18:00:57.020 2   NULL    2   0   0   0   0   0

Does anyone have any advice for me on what to do ??? So that I can add the index to my table and then I can get better performance... My next question is do I have to modify my SQL queries to add the SELECT 'ID' column to get the index performance increase in the SELECT and UPDATE Queries???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tries to create a copy of your table to facilitate a transaction.

Check a disk space where your transactional log is located. See if you need to flush a transactional log (according to your back up policy).

Comment: Apparently I am out of disk space or am low for log transaction file it's 52MB and there is only about 20 MB data... There are open transactions or active transactions and when I do log reuse wait description is says BackupLog which I think it the last thing I tried to do before so I could flush... I dont really know how to do any SQL admin procedures can you tell me what I am to do now?